# Can I pass double values to the main function of a c++ program?

Tags: c++

I am solving a problem where two different programs have to interact with each other. One program returns a vector which the other program (c++ program) has to work on with.

I have to call the c++ program from the command line. Is it possible to pass a vector of double values to that program - to the main function?

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way. The parameter to `argv` is always a `char **`.

Comment: Command line parameters are passed as strings. How you interpret them is up to you.

Comment: Using command-line parameters is not a good way to pass large amounts of data between processes. Especially binary data. There are a multitude of Inter-Process Communication (IPC) channels provided by the OS which you can utilize for this task instead.  For instance, pipes, sockets, shared memory, etc, just to name a few.

Comment: Use IPC, or serialize into a file. Unless you're dealing with a trifling amount of data, converting to and from strings is wasteful.

Comment: not only C++, no programming languages can receive any types other than string because that's what the caller passes to the process

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can. It works. As an example, I wrote this simple test using stdin and stdout. There is both a producer and consumer applications in one single source code. The producer takes an integer which will be the size of the vector and the consumer takes no arguments - that's how they distinguish themselves.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

void consumer() {
    int size;
    size_t res = ::fread(&size, sizeof(size), 1, stdin);
    assert(res == 1);
    std::vector<double> vec(size);
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        double value;
        res = ::fread(&value, sizeof(value), 1, stdin);
        assert(res == 1);
        vec[j] = value;
    }
    // print
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        ::printf("%d %f\n", j, vec[j]);
    }
}

void producer(int size) {
    // generate some fake numbers
    std::vector<double> vec(size);
    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        vec[j] = size - j;
    }

    // now send
    size_t res = ::fwrite(&size, sizeof(size), 1, stdout);
    assert(res == 1);
    for (double value : vec) {
        res = ::fwrite(&value, sizeof(value), 1, stdout);
        assert(res == 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        consumer();
    } else {
        int size = ::atoi(argv[1]);
        producer(size);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then run as

```cpp
$ g++ test_pipe.cpp -o test_pipe

$ ./test_pipe 10 | ./test_pipe
0 10.000000
1 9.000000
2 8.000000
3 7.000000
4 6.000000
5 5.000000
6 4.000000
7 3.000000
8 2.000000
9 1.000000
```

However doing this way you are monopolizing the standard streams stdin/stdout and that might be something you don't want to do, especially if you have other libraries included that might eventually print a warning message to stdout - and that will mess up your protocol.

In that case it is better to use a unix socket or even a TCP socket for communication.